# Controling GPU with shader model 2 from DirectX11 API

Tags: directx, directx-9, directx-11

Is it possible to somehow control gpu with shader model 2.0 via DirectX 11 API?

Use case is this: We have two types of render written in directx9. First is legacy for old GPUs and second is high quality render using shaders. We would like to transfer our high quality render to dx11, but still support older devices using legacy rendering. Is there some possibility for those to coexist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no. What you do in DX11 to support DX9 class hardware is use [10Level9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mode, create your device with [D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Overview) and compile your shaders with ps_4_0_level_9_1 target.